# If statement when getting data from php in twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to do an if statement with data passed to the twig file from the controller. Below is a line from the controller:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage', array('user' => $user, 'contact' => $contact)));
```

My goal is to do an if statement with the variable 'contact'. I checked the [twig reference](https://github.com/vito/chyrp/wiki/Twig-Reference) and it shows how to do an if statement but that would not work with 'contact'. Below is the code I tried, can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
{% if {{ contact.id }} > 0 %}
   {{ contact.addrLineOne }}
{% else %}
   --
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, just a small syntax modification will make your code working!

```
{% if contact.id > 0 %}
   {{ contact.addrLineOne }}
{% else %}
   --
{% endif %}
```

In Twig, curly braces means that you want to print **the value of a variable or an expression**. So you're statement in PHP would look like this :

```
if ((echo contact[id]) > 0)
    echo contact[addrLineOne]; // or contact->addrLineOne() according to the context
else
    --
```

Comment: Hmm...seems to be having some trouble again. I'm getting the below error:

Comment: Variable "contact" does not exist in AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:homepage.html.twig at line 32

line 32 is {% if contact.id > 0 %}

I have above the contact being passed in...is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: What version of twig do you use? Could you post your template code here.